# Files gone instead of renamed

Tags: bash

I wanted to rename some files to add the `.md` extension.  I ran the below command, but the files are gone. I am trying to understand why.

```
for i in $(ls); do cp "$i" "$(i)".md; done
```

Comment: Incidentally, note that `for i in $(ls)` is not very safe: it will give weird results if any filenames contain any interesting/unusual characters (such as spaces). Instead, you should write `for i in *`. (See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more information.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"$(i)"
```

Runs the command `i` and places the result in the string. Since you don't have a `i` command, this means that your main command could be written as:

```
for i in $(ls); do cp "$i" .md; done
```

If you have 2 files in your folder, lets say `a.txt` and `b.txt`, this effectively executes:

```
cp a.txt .md
cp b.txt .md
```

this doesn't delete anything, but it copies both files to a file named `.md`. This happens twice, so only the last survives.

Maybe this hidden file is not showing up because files starting with a `.` are sometimes hidden.